# Why can't I run the project on port 5000?

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm trying to run a Node JS project on port 5000, but I can't:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

It would seem that everything is simple, but:

```
lsof -i tcp:5000
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 395 colibri  22u  IPv4 0x361e8dfd90bd1ee9      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 395 colibri  23u  IPv6 0x361e8dfd8b640a61      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

"ControlCe" is the "ControlCenter" from macOS 12.0.1.

Can you please tell me if there is a way to run applications on port 5000, or now I need to use, for example, port 5010?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apple uses port 5000 for AirPlay Receiver.

If you need to, you can disable this in System Preferences > Sharing > AirPlay Receiver. Personally, I would just shift to a different, available port.

Comment: Is there also a way to disable it via console?

Comment: @sunwarr10r Possible options are described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431846/toggle-airplay-receiver-server-with-the-command-line-on-macos-monteray) and [here](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/disabling-airplay-receiver/m-p/254648).